# How to grant file read/write permission in a Security Manager policy file for variable parent directories

Tags: java, junit, securitymanager

I'm learning to use Security Manager, and I'm getting this error when I run my unit tests:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4\executor-snippets\junitvmwatcher1469887727677239882.properties" "write")
```

It's simple enough grant permission to that directory. The problem is I run this code on different computers. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "*/NetBeans/Cache/7.4/-", "write";
```

But apparently SecurityManager doesn't recognize wildcard characters at the beginning of the path. I've tried using both an asterisk and a dash. Neither works.

Basically, I'd like to get my tests to run without needing to hard-code an absolute path. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: To clarify: The test do run successfully when I hard-code the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [property expansion in policy files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#PropertyExp):

> For example, permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.home}", "read";
>   will expand "${user.home}" to use the value of the "user.home" system property.

Could you set:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.home}/AppData/Local/NetBeans/-", "write";
```

to get what you wanted?

Comment: I ended up not solving this. The requirements of the project changed such that I no longer need to use Security Manager during unit tests. However this looks exactly like the type of answer I was looking for. Though some computers didn't put it under the user.home directory, this could easily be adapted to what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that it works (at least for me)!